# Push element in array depending of conditionnal elements number in this array in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have this collection of `things` :

```
db={
  "things": [
    {
      _id: 1,
      users: [
        {
          userId: 1,
          role: "creator"
        },{
          userId: 2,
          role: "spectator"
        },{
          userId: 3,
          role: "left"
        }
      ],
      nbMax:2
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      users: [
        {
          userId: 2,
          role: "creator"
        },{
          userId: 1,
          role: "spectator"
        },{
          userId: 3,
          role: "left"
        }
      ],
      nbMax:3
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to push a new user in `users` field for a given `_id` with this condition :
the number of users with role `creator` and `spectator` must be lower than the field `nbMax`

In this example :

Pushing a new user for `_id` : 1 does not work since `nbMax` = 2 and there already is 1 creator and 1 spectator (`left` does not count)

Pushing a new user for `_id` : 2 works because `nbMax` = 3 and there already is only 1 creator and 1 spectator.

Is there a way to perform that with mongodb or should I rather split this query in 2 queries in nodejs like :
_ checking users size and `nbMax`
_ if it's ok : push a new user

I have tried queries using `update`, `aggregate` with `$size` but nothing works so far, I am wondering if what I want to do is a good mongodb practice.

edit : I have created an `aggregate` giving me the number of users being `creator` or `spectator` for an given _id :

```
db.things.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$users"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "users.role": {
        $in: [
          "creator",
          "spectator"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": 1,
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This is a [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JfVpJuAo78x)